# R: Why does changing the key of one base table causes the columns in the newly joined table to sort independently?

Tags: r, data.table

**EDIT:** It appears the issue was due to a bug in the versions of R and data.table I was using. Thank you to @Arun for pointing it out.

I'm having a problem using datatables in R where calling `setkey(DT,x)` directly after joining two data.tables (using syntax `X[Y]`) is causing the columns of the newly joined table to resort independently of each other, causing values to be disassociated from one another. Note that this doesn't happen if I perform operations on the newly joined table before I call `setkey`.

I have `data.table ab` and `data.table bc`:

```
> ab
    a  b
1:  1  A
2:  2  B
3:  3  C
4:  4  D
5:  5  E
6:  6  F
7:  1  G

> bc
    b  c
1:  A  101
2:  B  102
3:  C  103
4:  D  104
5:  E  105
6:  F  106
7:  G  101
```

Joining the two after assigning keys gives the expected result:

```
> setkey(ab, b)
> setkey(bc, b)
> comb <- ab[bc]
> comb
    b  a  c
1:  A  1  101
2:  B  2  102
3:  C  3  103
4:  D  4  104
5:  E  5  105
6:  F  6  106
7:  G  7  101
```

But then when I call `setkey` to change the key of `bc` to `c`, the values in `comb` change, as if columns `b` and `c` have been sorted independent of column `a`:

```
> setkey(bc, c)
> comb
    b  a  c
1:  A  1  101
2:  G  2  101
3:  B  3  102
4:  C  4  103
5:  D  5  104
6:  E  6  105
7:  F  1  106
```

Why would calling `setkey(DT,x)` cause columns in a new `data.table` created by joining `DT` to another table cause columns in the new table to resort independent of other columns?

Here is my `sessionInfo()`:

```
R version 3.1.1 (2014-07-10)
Platform: i386-w64-mingw32/i386 (32-bit)

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=English_United States.1252  LC_CTYPE=English_United States.1252   
[3] LC_MONETARY=English_United States.1252 LC_NUMERIC=C                          
[5] LC_TIME=English_United States.1252    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] data.table_1.9.2

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] plyr_1.8.1    Rcpp_0.11.2   reshape2_1.4  stringr_0.6.2 tools_3.1.1
```

Comment: Huh?!? It shouldn't, and doesn't happen for me. Could you edit your post with `sessionInfo()` please?

Comment: There are `a,b` and `b,c` columns in data.tables `ab` and `bc`. But your result has a column `d`... ?

Comment: Updated with `sessionInfo()`. Also corrected - column `d` should have been `c`.

Comment: I think this is related to the new changes in R3.1.1 (shallow copy), and IIUC this was fixed in 1.9.4. Please install it from CRAN and try again.

Comment: That worked for my test data - now to make sure it solved the problem overall.

Comment: An update to R3.1.2 and data.table 1.9.4 fixed the issue. I'm glad this is a newly introduced bug - I some data last year with the same script under an earlier version of R and didn't notice the issue.

Answer (score 1):

The above behavior was due to a bug in the version of R (3.1.1) and data.table (1.9.2). Updating R to version 3.1.2 and data.table to 1.9.4 resolved the issue and behavior is as expected.

Thanks to @Arun for suggesting I update.